# Generate header amalgamation from multiple header and source files?

Tags: c, cmake, header-files, libclang, amalgamation

I've been using a header-only library, but it has actually separated it out into header (`*.h`) and source (`*.c`) files.

[SQLite creates a single file](https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html)—primarily for other reasons related to optimisation—so I was wondering if there's an automated way of generated one header *amalgamation* from multiple header and source files.

(I've tried manually by running [`SUBSTRING`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#substring) in my `CMakeLists.txt`)

The advantage is skipping a [`target_link_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) step is in build speed, distribution, and simpler help text.

I could probably write something with [LLVM](https://llvm.org)'s [LibTooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html) or [LibClang](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html)… but this seems like a common use case that others have solved expertly.

How do I *automatically* generate one amalgamated header from multiple header and source files?

Comment: PS: Here's my `SUBSTRING` attempt: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/17343#issuecomment-822283204

Comment: SQLite uses a Tcl script [mksqlite3.c.tcl](https://sqlite.org/src/file?name=tool/mksqlite3c.tcl&ci=trunk) to do that. Most of the projects I've worked on or seen use a scripting language for file pre-processing like this.